# Can Sprite kit be used in app development in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

Could you tell me , is `SpriteKit` is suitable for apps development.
Because the design of the app that i going to make is fully new . That has no relationship with ios design. The design is completely new.
It was built using html5,CSS . Could you plz let me know, does sprite kit helps in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you tell me , is SpriteKit is suitable for apps development.

Yes, of course. It's a framework provided by apple for app development. So it's pretty obvious that it is suitable for developing apps.

> It was built using html5,CSS . Could you plz let me know, does sprite
>   kit helps in this manner?

SpriteKit helps you for developing 2D games. So yes, it does help you, as long as you only want to create a 2D game. You should start with Apples [About Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn more about things like `SKSpriteNode`, `SKTexture`, `SKScene` etc.